# Кодировка на выходе

Tags: python, кодировка

В соседнем блоге был задан вопрос о том как убрать слово по его последней букве. Вот мой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

text = raw_input()
sym = raw_input ()

text = text.split ()

it = []
for slovo in text:
    slovo = list (slovo)
    if slovo[-1] != sym:
        slovo = "".join (slovo)
        it.append (slovo)
print it
```

Но почему то этот скрипт работает только на анг раскладке и если убрать 2 строку о кодировке. Иначе  print выдает ответ в юникоде. Как это исправить? А то вроде и ответил, и ответ такой не опублкуешь человеку.... У меня Python стоит 2.7.3, вроде раньше такого не замечал...

Comment: @Asid, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: я что то не помню что бы она так писалась, пробовали так :

    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: А как? тогда правильно?

Comment: sonniy, наверное, имел ввиду написать utf-8, а не UTF-8.

Comment: Пробовал, уважаемый Sonniy, изменил как вы подсказываете, но ответ то же - сплошной юникод.  Проверьте сами, введите "Жили у бабуси два веселых гуся" и во второй раз букву "и". По идее ответ должен быть: "у два веселых гуся".

Comment: Вот пробовал через терминал тестить:
 ~ $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> we = "привет все, тест кодировки"
>>> we
'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5, \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82 \xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8'
>>> print we
привет все, тест кодировки
>>>

Comment: А зачем переделывать строку в список?  
Разве последняя буква не находится так?  

    slovo[-1]
А переделав в список Вы наталкиваетесь на то, что в слове каждая буква представлена двумя байтами, а Вы берете только один байт из двух.  Не знаю, будет ли работать Ваш код в 3.х, но в любой версии питона такой подход неверен.

Comment: @Vorlog у человека изначально было написано :

    -- coding: UTF-8 --

Comment: @Asid вы бы как нибудь выкроили время и по отмечали принятые ответы

Comment: Да, уважаемый, компьютеры это просто хобби для души, и у меня в обед или еще где то время появляется смотрю что можно сделать самому и кто на какую светлую мысль подтолкнул. Хотя планы на ближайшее время - вспомнить экстренно физику\алгебру и поступить в университет). Это малость отвлекает от програмирования и изучению англицкого.....

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что Вы используете python2.x, а в нем тип str не поддерживает юникод, а является по сути просто последовательностью байтов. Для работы со строкой в юникоде переведите полученные строки в юникод

```
text = text.decode('utf-8')
sym = sym.decode('utf-8')
```

Строка типа

```
 # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

только указывает интерпретатору, в какой кодировке написан текст программы и нужна для того, чтобы он понимал и принимал комментарии, строки  и пр., написанные на кириллице

Comment: Пробовал вставлял после raw_input, результат тот же.

Comment: text.decode('utf-8') - декодирует из utf-8, или декодирует последовательность байт из чего-то там в utf-8?

Comment: и на выходе вы можете получить [такую кашу][1], что создатель той стринги буде тихо плакать в уголке


  [1]: http://cn12.nevsedoma.com.ua/photo/129/1/podbormI.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Отображать нужно не список, а элемент списка

```
print it
```

на

```
print it[0]
```

ЗЫ
конец вашего скрипта выглядит у меня так:

```
print it
print it[0]

sonniy@sonniy-pc:~/Документы$ python test.py 
Жили у бабуси два веселых гуся
и
['\xd0\x96\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8', '\xd1\x83', '\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8', '\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0', '\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b\xd1\x85', '\xd0\xb3\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x8f']
Жили
```

а можно еще так :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

text = raw_input()
sym = raw_input ()

text = text.split ()

it = []
for slovo in text:
    slovo = list (slovo)
    if slovo[-1] != sym:
        slovo = "".join (slovo)+' ' 
        it.append (slovo)
print ''.join(it)
```

**UPD**
Помню что то такое хитрое было со списками но забыл что именно, порылся и нашел :

> При выводе списка, происходит вызов
> `[{repr}]()` который возвращает
> внутреннее представление этого спиcка.
> Для корректного вывода списка, его
> нужно преобразовать в строку.

[источник](http://www.py-my.ru/post/4bfb3c6a1d41c846bc00009b)

Comment: sonniy, спасибо. print  ведет себя адекватно. Не адекватно ведет себя slovo в контексте итератора. Там идет ошибка, похоже в следствие кодировки, и вместо него неотображаемый символ ("print slovo" после условия). Поэтому вся программа идет лесом. Пока самый адекватный вариант - это на python3...... А по тексту так и не скажешь что тут где то баг:)

Comment: Так на всякий случай,а какая у Вас ОС ?

Comment: Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon..... 64-bit.....